# Archiving content in SharePoint libraries

Tags: c#

I have the following `using` statement, used specifically for the purpose of archiving content in SharePoint libraries. In this statement my objects are disposed in two places:

```
finally
{
    web.Dispose();
    site.Dispose();
}
```

and at the termination of my `using` statement.

The full `using` statement is:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(connectionString))
            {

                SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(); // open the site
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Opened site: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), web);
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Web Relative URL is: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), web.ServerRelativeUrl);

                try
                {
                    // Get your source and destination libraries
                    var source = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + @"/Approval%20History%20%20Sales1");
                    var destination = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + @"/Approval%20History%20%20Sales");

                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Source set to: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), source);
                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Destination set to: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), destination);

                    // Get the collection of items to move, use source.GetItems(SPQuery) if you want a subset
                    SPListItemCollection items = source.Items;

                    // Get the root folder of the destination we'll use this to add the files
                    SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url);

                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Moving {1} files from {2} to {3} - please wait...", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
                                      items.Count, source, destination);

                    // Now to move the files and the metadata
                    foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                    {
                        //Get the file associated with the item
                        SPFile file = item.File;

                        // Create a new file in the destination library with the same properties
                        SPFile newFile = folder.Files.Add(folder.Url + "/" + file.Name, file.OpenBinary(), file.Properties, true);

                        // Optionally copy across the created/modified metadata                        
                        SPListItem newItem = newFile.Item;
                        newItem["Editor"] = item["Editor"];
                        newItem["Modified"] = item["Modified"];
                        newItem["Modified By"] = item["Modified By"];
                        newItem["Author"] = item["Author"];
                        newItem["Created"] = item["Created"];
                        newItem["Created By"] = item["Created By"];

                        // UpdateOverwriteVersion() will preserve the metadata added above. 
                        newItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();

                        // Delete the original version of the file
                        // todo: make local backup before deleting?
                        file.Delete();
                        fileCount++;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Completed moving {1} files to {2}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), fileCount,
                                      destination);
                }
                catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Unable to set a location. Please check that paths for source and destination libraries are correct and relative to the site collection.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    web.Dispose();
                    site.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

Is my `finally` statement here redundant? Is there any reason that even if potentially it *is* redundant that I should retain it anyway?

Comment: I recommend reading this item, even though there is a better construct in c# 4.0 http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9780321659149/dotnet-resource-management/ch02lev1sec4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, one is redundant, `Dispose()` on the `site` object is done for you automatically in the context of `using`. To be idiomatic in C#, you should do the following:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(connectionString))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) // open the site
{
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Opened site: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), web);
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Web Relative URL is: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), web.ServerRelativeUrl);

            // Get your source and destination libraries
            var source = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + @"/Approval%20History%20%20Sales1");
            var destination = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + @"/Approval%20History%20%20Sales");

            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Source set to: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), source);
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Destination set to: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), destination);

            // Get the collection of items to move, use source.GetItems(SPQuery) if you want a subset
            SPListItemCollection items = source.Items;

            // Get the root folder of the destination we'll use this to add the files
            SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url);

            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Moving {1} files from {2} to {3} - please wait...", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
                              items.Count, source, destination);

            // Now to move the files and the metadata
            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
            {
                //Get the file associated with the item
                SPFile file = item.File;

                // Create a new file in the destination library with the same properties
                SPFile newFile = folder.Files.Add(folder.Url + "/" + file.Name, file.OpenBinary(), file.Properties, true);

                // Optionally copy across the created/modified metadata                        
                SPListItem newItem = newFile.Item;
                newItem["Editor"] = item["Editor"];
                newItem["Modified"] = item["Modified"];
                newItem["Modified By"] = item["Modified By"];
                newItem["Author"] = item["Author"];
                newItem["Created"] = item["Created"];
                newItem["Created By"] = item["Created By"];

                // UpdateOverwriteVersion() will preserve the metadata added above. 
                newItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();

                // Delete the original version of the file
                // todo: make local backup before deleting?
                file.Delete();
                fileCount++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Completed moving {1} files to {2}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), fileCount,
                              destination);
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Unable to set a location. Please check that paths for source and destination libraries are correct and relative to the site collection.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to have to call dispose on site, the using statement takes care of it.

On the same note, the web variable should be wrapped in a using statement too, then the finally block is redundant.

```
using (var site = new SPSite(connectionString))
{
    using(var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

[Microsoft Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to use RAII above `finally`; you are already doing this with `site`, so disposing of it in the `finally` doesn't make much sense.  On the other hand, you are not disposing of `web` that way and I would say that this could leak to (extremely unlikely) errors.  For example, if `web.ServerRelativeUrl` was a property and threw, you would now fail to dispose of `web` correctly.

Comment: I think you can't call `using` RAII. It serves a very similar purpose, but it is not the same.

Comment: @svick: Why not?  It is definitely SBRM, which is generally considered a synonym for it as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the logic of the `Dispose` implementation in each class:

If the class can tolerate consequent invocations to its `Dispose` method, then all is fine and dandy.

If not, then, maybe an exception would be thrown...

In any case, I would avoid invoking a `Dispose` method more than once - indicates a code smell.

Comment: [“If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one.”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) So, all `IDisposable` types should work fine with multiple invocations of `Dispose()`.

Comment: @svick, that's theory. In practice, it's totally up to the developer if to follow this instruction or not...